# How to get the size of an element in array those starts with the "name" followed by a number Eg: name1, name20 etc

Tags: java, arrays

I have been asked to find the size of the array which is a keyset of a map params having key starts with "name" followed by the any number.

```
params.keySet()
```

The above code gives the array of keys which is something like below.

> [name6, name3, id, name, version, access-id, password, name2, name7,
>   name1, type, name4]

I have tried the following which worked for me, now problem is to implement this without iteration.

```
int nameSize=0;
for(String paramKey : params.keySet()){
   if(paramKey.startsWith("name[0-9]"))
      nameSize++;
    }
System.out.println("The size of the name is : "+nameSize);
```

my expected output is:

> The size of the name is : 6

Please help me in doing this without iterating each element in the array.

Comment: Of course you have to iterate the `Set` (**not** array, you said so yourself). You can do `keySet.stream().filter(key -> key.matches("name\\d++")).count()`, but that just internalises the iteration.

Comment: Or of couse the way you did it but replace paramKey.startsWith("name[0-9]") with paramKey.matches("name\\d+")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a regular expression (`startsWith` does not accept a regular expression, which you were trying):

```
String[] s = {"name6", "name3", "id", "name", "version",
            "access-id", "password", "name2", "name7", "name1", "type", "name4", "ARGHname3ARGH"};

Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^name\\d+");
long l = Arrays.stream(s).filter(p.asPredicate()).count();
```

#### EDIT:

and yes this iterates as well over each element, but might do so using multiple threads

#### EDIT 2 (request for Java <=7)

You can use google's guave when you are not working on Java 8

```
String[] s = {"name6", "name3", "id", "name", "version",
        "access-id", "password", "name2", "name7", "name1", "type", "name4"};
List<String> s2 = Arrays.asList(s);
int size = Collections2.filter(s2, Predicates.containsPattern("^name\\d+")).size();
```

Comment: It will works fine for Java 8 but my code base is stick to java 7 any suggestion on achieving this on java 7

Comment: I added a java 7 example

Comment: Your "_Java <=7_" solution requires Guava - could you not provide a solution that is just JDK based? Further, why copy before `filter`?

Comment: @BoristheSpider because he is trying to use a regular expression on `startsWith` which won't work.

Comment: @BoristheSpider yes you are right. Changed to "could"

Comment: Also, `Predicates.containsPattern` won't work as it `contains` rather than `mathces` - `ARGHname3ARGH` would match for example. `^name\\d++$`.

Comment: @BoristheSpider added ^

Comment: @BoristheSpider as is to his requirement "having key starts with "name" followed by the any number"

Comment: @rparree the examples the OP (how do you know the OP is male?) gives are `name1` and `name20` - I would conjecture that the OP doesn't want to match `name1name` or anything in that vein.

Answer (score -2):

"name" is not equals "name0".

```
if(paramKey.startWith("name[0-9]") || paramKey.equals("name"))
    nameSize++;
```

or

```
if(paramKey.startWith("name"))
    nameSize++;
```

Comment: i don't want to include "name" instead "name" followed by at-least a number